# FindDragTarget does not detect disabled controls

Tags: delphi, delphi-10.1-berlin

Create a Delphi VCL Forms Application and put 2 `TButton` and a `TApplicationEvents` on the form:

[image]

Then insert these event-handlers:

```
unit Unit2;

interface

uses
  Winapi.Windows, Winapi.Messages, System.SysUtils, System.Variants, System.Classes, Vcl.Graphics,
  Vcl.Controls, Vcl.Forms, Vcl.Dialogs, Vcl.StdCtrls, Vcl.AppEvnts;

type
  TForm2 = class(TForm)
    Button1: TButton;
    Button2: TButton;
    ApplicationEvents1: TApplicationEvents;
    procedure ApplicationEvents1Message(var Msg: tagMSG; var Handled: Boolean);
    procedure Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
  private
    { Private declarations }
  public
    { Public declarations }
  end;

var
  Form2: TForm2;

implementation

{$R *.dfm}

procedure TForm2.Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
begin
  Screen.Cursor := crHelp;
end;

procedure TForm2.ApplicationEvents1Message(var Msg: tagMSG; var Handled: Boolean);
var
  Target: TControl;
  Point: TPoint;
begin
  if Msg.Message = WM_LBUTTONDOWN then
  begin
    if Screen.Cursor = crHelp then
    begin
      Screen.Cursor := crDefault;
      Handled := True;
      GetCursorPos(Point);
      Target := FindDragTarget(Point, True);
      if Assigned(Target) then
        ShowMessage(Target.Name)
      else
        ShowMessage(IntToStr(Point.X) + ', ' + IntToStr(Point.Y));
    end;
  end;
end;

end.
```

Now click on **Button1** to change the mouse pointer to `crHelp`.

Then click again on **Button1** which correctly shows the name "Button1".

Now click again on **Button1** to change the mouse pointer again to `crHelp`.

Then click on the disabled **Button2**: You can see that now `FindDragTarget` has not detected the disabled control although the argument `AllowDisabled` is set to `True`.

So how can I detect a disabled control with a mouse-click?

Delphi 10.1.2

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The "problem" (this is actually by design) is that the `FindDragTarget` function does not check for disabled child *Windowed* Controls.

```
function FindDragTarget(const Pos: TPoint; AllowDisabled: Boolean): TControl;
var
  Window: TWinControl;
  Control: TControl;
begin
  ...
  Control := Window.ControlAtPos(Window.ScreenToClient(Pos), AllowDisabled);
  ...
end;
```

Note that `Window.ControlAtPos` only passes `AllowDisabled` argument but NOT the `AllowWinControls` (which is `False` by default).

`FindDragTarget` will only find child `TGraphicControl` descendant controls (which use their parent Handle).

You can use this function instead:

```
function FindDragTargetEx(const Pos: TPoint; AllowDisabled: Boolean; AllowWinControls: Boolean): TControl;
var
  Window: TWinControl;
  Control: TControl;
begin
  Result := nil;
  Window := FindVCLWindow(Pos);
  if Window <> nil then
  begin
    Result := Window;
    Control := Window.ControlAtPos(Window.ScreenToClient(Pos), AllowDisabled, AllowWinControls);
    if Control <> nil then Result := Control;
  end;
end;
```